# ImageResizer prefix error

Tags: c#, azure-blob-storage, imageresizer

I'm using Image Resizer [AzureReader 2](http://imageresizing.net/docs/v4/plugins/azurereader2)

This used to work perfectly and I don't think I upgraded any other projects that have dependencies outside of the indicated acceptable limits. (All versions match the required versions)

The prefix setting seems to be causing an error.
When I have prefix="~/" I get the error below.

But when I don't include the prefix setting (so it defaults to "~/azure") or I set it to prefix="~/images" everything works perfectly, but then obviously I have to have a prefix which I don't want.

So basically https://example.com/images/myimage.jpeg
With prefix="~/" throws the below error

But https://example.com/azure/images/myimage.jpeg
With prefix="~/azure" works perfectly

Where images is the name of the blob and myimage.jpeg is the name of the image.

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:

> [WebException: The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.] 
>   Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Shared.Protocol.HttpResponseParsers.ProcessExpectedStatusCodeNoException(HttpStatusCode
>   expectedStatusCode, HttpStatusCode actualStatusCode, T retVal,
>   StorageCommandBase`1 cmd, Exception ex) in c:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\release_dotnet_master\Lib\Common\Shared\Protocol\HttpResponseParsers.Common.cs:50
>   Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.<>c__DisplayClass13.<GetBlobReferenceImpl>b__12(RESTCommand`1
>   cmd, HttpWebResponse resp, Exception ex, OperationContext ctx) in
>   c:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\release_dotnet_master\Lib\ClassLibraryCommon\Blob\CloudBlobClient.cs:793
>   Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.Executor.Executor.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult
>   getResponseResult) in c:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\release_dotnet_master\Lib\ClassLibraryCommon\Core\Executor\Executor.cs:299
>
> [StorageException: The remote server returned an error: (404) Not
>   Found.]
>   Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.Executor.Executor.EndExecuteAsync(IAsyncResult
>   result) in c:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\release_dotnet_master\Lib\ClassLibraryCommon\Core\Executor\Executor.cs:50
>   Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.CloudBlobClient.EndGetBlobReferenceFromServer(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) in c:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\release_dotnet_master\Lib\ClassLibraryCommon\Blob\CloudBlobClient.cs:635
>   Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.Util.<>c__DisplayClass1`1.b__0(IAsyncResult
>   ar) in c:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\release_dotnet_master\Lib\ClassLibraryCommon\Core\Util\AsyncExtensions.cs:66
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) +99
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) +58
>   ImageResizer.Plugins.AzureReader2.d__14.MoveNext() +209
>
> [FileNotFoundException: Azure blob file not found]
>   ImageResizer.Plugins.AzureReader2.d__14.MoveNext() +409
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) +99
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) +58    ImageResizer.Util.AsyncUtils.RunSync(Func`1 func) +159
>
>   ImageResizer.Storage.Blob.Open() in
>   C:\projects\resizer\Plugins\ImageResizer.Storage\Blob.cs:41
>
>   ImageResizer.Plugins.VirtualFileShim.Open() +11
>
>   System.Web.WebPages.BuildManagerWrapper.IsNonUpdateablePrecompiledApp(VirtualPathProvider
>   vpp, IVirtualPathUtility virtualPathUtility) +86
>
>   System.Web.WebPages.BuildManagerWrapper.IsNonUpdatablePrecompiledApp()
>   +36    System.Web.WebPages.BuildManagerWrapper..ctor(Func`1 vppFunc, IVirtualPathUtility virtualPathUtility) +36
>   System.Web.WebPages.BuildManagerWrapper..ctor() +102
>   System.Web.WebPages.VirtualPathFactoryManager.<.cctor>b__3() +24
>   System.Lazy`1.CreateValue() +411    System.Lazy`1.LazyInitValue() +152
>   System.Lazy`1.get_Value() +75
>
>   System.Web.WebPages.VirtualPathFactoryManager.get_Instance() +27
>
>   System.Web.WebPages.ApplicationStartPage.ExecuteStartPage(HttpApplication
>   application) +96
>
>   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageHttpModule.StartApplication(HttpApplication
>   application, Action`1 executeStartPage, EventHandler applicationStart)
>   +94    System.Web.WebPages.WebPageHttpModule.StartApplication(HttpApplication
>   application) +54
>   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageHttpModule.Init(HttpApplication
>   application) +200
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(IntPtr
>   appContext, HttpContext context, MethodInfo[] handlers) +534
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.InitSpecial(HttpApplicationState state,
>   MethodInfo[] handlers, IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +172
>   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr
>   appContext, HttpContext context) +339
>   System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr
>   appContext) +296
>
> [HttpException (0x80004005): Azure blob file not found]
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +9923092 
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +90
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest
>   wr, HttpContext context) +261

```
<plugins>
      <add name="MvcRoutingShim" />
      <add name="AzureReader2"
           connectionString="" 
           endpoint="https://images.blob.core.windows.net/"
           prefix="~/"
           />
    </plugins>
```

Comment: And on which URL are you getting this error?

Comment: Well before it worked just fine on localhost:port/images/id where images is the name but now if I have prefix set to ~/ that throws the error listed above if I put prefix to nothing or ~/azure and go to localhost:port/azure/images/Id it works perfectly

Comment: The only thing I've changed in my projects is I've upgraded some of the azure projects, and the image resizer projects (Like I removed the deprecated mvc project), but they are all within compatible limits.

Comment: We suggest avoiding mounting the provider as root, as you're forcing it to check all incoming URLs. Prefixes are strongly encouraged. That said, if you give us a specific URL that causes this as well as the expected underlying blob  URL, we may be able to make progress.

Comment: For now I'm just trying to get it working locally so the direct link to the image would be http://127.0.0.1:10000/devstoreaccount1/images/test.jpeg. And I am trying to access it through http://localhost:57474/images/test.jpeg?width=200. 

<add name="AzureReader2" prefix="~/" connectionString="UseDevelopmentStorage=true" endpoint="http://127.0.0.1:10000/devstoreaccount1/" redirectToBlobIfUnmodified="false" />

Comment: This used to work and now it doesn't. I'm using ImageResizer4.0.4, ImageResizer.FluentExtensions1.0.0.5, ImageResizer.FluentExtensions.MVC1.0.0.6, ImageResizer.Plugins.AzureReader2.4.0.4, ImageResizer.Storage.4.0.4, ImageResizer.Mvc.3.4.3, Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc5.2.3, WindowsAzure.Storage 4.0.4 and Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ConfigurationManager.3.1.0